# Extract a particular substring from value

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

The result of a particular query is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Attachment content-type="application/temp" name="123_PQ_ABCDEFG_160720190439.tmp"/>
```

I want to be able to get the 3 digit number starting with `12` [`123` in this case] from  `name="123_PQ_ABCDEFG_160720190439.tmp"`

Note: All 3 digit numbers will start with "12". 3rd digit could be anything[0-9].

```
with test as (
    select '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Attachment content-type="application/ms-excel" name="123_PQ_ABCDEFG_160720190439.tmp"/>' code from dual
)
select code,
CASE
WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(code, '^[12]')
THEN SUBSTR(code,1,3)
END AS code
from test
```

Looking to check with strings that start with 12 and then get a substring of only the 3 digits.

Expected Result: 123
Actual Result: null

Comment: but your text doesn't start with `12`, it starts with `<?xml`.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I want the substring within the whole string that starts with 12.

Comment: Is in every case, you are looking only for the something after 12.?? and does it have only 3 digits.. then you can also normal substr function.. in the example code, system is trying to look for a string that start with 12 but in the data, 12 is in middle of the string.. hence you are getting result as null..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if u don't need regex,
try this

```
with test as (
    select '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Attachment content-type="application/ms-excel" name="123_PQ_ABCDEFG_160720190439.tmp"/>' code from dual
)
select code,
 SUBSTR(code,instr(code,'name="')+6,3) code
from test
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this  regexp:

```
with test as (
    select '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Attachment content-type="application/ms-excel" name="123_PQ_ABCDEFG_160720190439.tmp"/>' code from dual
)
select 
 REGEXP_substr(REGEXP_substr(code, '[(name=")](1)(2)(\d)',1,1), '(1)(2)(\d)',1,1)
  AS code_substr,
 code
from test
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=430636ac95a84a1643360e1bd9bd7cb6)

Cheers!!